# Can i update an existing ec2 instance with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform

Is it possible to edit an existing resource example: an ec2 instance with the terraform template.
Ex: I have a ec2 instance created with aws console, can i add that ec2 instance to add a new security group using the instance id in terraform template. I know this can't be done with cloud formation. Currently I can do this with Ansible, but i don't see a way to do it with terraform or cloudformation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can! However you have to then manage the instance with Terraform. There's no way to just "Do this to a running instance" and call it a day - that's what the various SDKs are for and the AWS CLI.

What you're looking for is [terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) - to use this, you'll want to define a resource in your Terraform configuration, map up everything how you want, and then import that resource.

Since you're using an [EC2 instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#import), it will look something like:

```
terraform import aws_instance.web i-12345678
```

Once this is done; if you do a `terraform plan` you can see what attributes you forgot to add to your configuration you setup for this - add those in, and then you can start managing this resource.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, let me try this. Also is it possible to do the same with cloud formation

Comment: No idea - sorry; I only use Terraform.

Comment: is it possible to modify the resource in the same template after it's created in the next task. I know no, but if there is a way or hack to do it

Comment: You CAN modify a resource that you have imported. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah, no, what i want is to modify the resource that i created in the same template in the same execution