# Reference an existing EC2 node's public IP-address in Terraform configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have some terraform providers depending upon the public IP-address of an existing EC2 node. I've seen in a [similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720442/can-i-update-an-existing-ec2-instance-with-terraform) that you can *import* an existing node by setting up a matching resource entry then run `terraform import` to import it:

`terraform import aws_instance.test i-12345678`

However, when I run it (with the correct instance-ID, of course) I get this error:

```
Error importing: Provider "kov" depends on non-var "aws_instance.test.0/aws_instance.test.N". Providers for import can currently
only depend on variables or must be hardcoded. You can stop import
from loading configurations by specifying `-config=""`.
```

The config for the above command is:

```
provider "aws" {
    # ...
}
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
    ami = "ami-blablahblah"
    instance_type = "t2.large"
    # ...
}
provider "kov" {
    host = "${aws_instance.test.public_ip}"
    port = 8080
    # ...
}
```

The additional provider uses that host and port to configure other servers that connect to it. Any ideas to get that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to import resources if all you want is to refer to them in some way.

Take a look at the `aws_instance` data source: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instance.html

```
data "aws_instance" "test" {
  instance_id = "i-12345678"
}
```

You should then be able to access `public_ip` from the data source.

Comment: Data! Thank you Manoj! I followed: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html

with the resulting config that now works:

data "aws_instance" "test" {
  instance_id = "i-0510daa152c5901dc"
}

provider "solace" {
  host           = "${data.aws_instance.test.public_ip}"
# ...
}

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to followup based on @manojlds's helpful answer. The working configuration looks like this:

```
provider "aws" {
    # ...
}
data "aws_instance" "test" {
    instance_type = "t2.large"
}
provider "kov" {
    host = "${data.aws_instance.test.public_ip}"
    # ...
}
```

Even better, I can filter the data source based on other attributes so I don't necessarily need to know the instance-id upfront.